# How my species powers work?

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology

My species live in a planet which was like prehistoric earth where dinosaur lived. My species name was trialsapien. The bones on the arms  of evolved trialsapien become kinetically charged and unstable that they create explosion upon collision of the fists. Once they evolved, they gain the combined traits of Ankylosaurus and Triceratops and the unstable kinetic energy heavily mutated their biology, harden the muscle tissues with powerful mineral that rivals metals and such pressure cause them to become visible on the flesh.

The healing factor grew abnormal that, when the kinetic energy destroyed the hand, it mold the flesh into what they calls "Repeating Plasma Cannon", which the evolved trialsapien can now exhausted the energy by discharging them as explosive bone fragments, all while the regeneration immediately replaced them. When not in use, the factor fully regenerates the hands. My organism can launch rocket like (not cyborg) bombs from it's hands which can explode with so much power that it can destroy anything in one shot. HOW my organism can create this bomb?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered without copious amounts of Handwaivium.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Handwavium solves the problem. It is the handwavium that makes their fists explode when they shake them about

Comment: I don't often vote to close as opinion-based, but here I did. You've defined your creatures and what they can do. What's the question? What do you mean, "how my organism can do this?" Are you asking us to physiologically create the creature? To "realistically" define something that can instantly manifest a plasma cannon and then later replace it with a hand? That's not possible and outside the bounds of a Stack that has as its primary goal the desire to help you create an imaginary world. But I might be understanding your goals. What, specifically, are you asking for?

Answer (score 3):

## Magic (and alcohol)

[image]

The species was created by a Master Wizard on an alcohol bender. Wizards love practical jokes. Wizard thought it would be funny if whenever his two best friends Jessica and Alexander do a high-five there was a massive explosion.

The designated driver suggested the joke was too extreme and would kill both participants. Then they could not high-five ever again or appreciate how funny it is, since they are now deceased.

Wizard agreed but since explosions are sicknasty, he compromised to keep the explosion but add monstrous healing factor to the spell.

The joke was so well received, the Wizard did the same the following long weekend. Only this time he found a planet and placed the spell on the whole dominant species.

He later (alcohol again) forgot to turn the spell off. Thus the Trialsapiens were born.

Comment: +1 just for making me laugh in complete confusion over the idea of an "alcohol bender." It took me a moment to connect it with the idea of "going on a bender." My first thought was that your wizard was bending alcohol (aka, The Last Airbender), which had far too much in common with Terry Pratchett's ludicrous Bilious, the Oh-God of Hangovers.